# numba: How to delete an existing array and assign a new array to the old array's name?

Tags: python, numpy, numba

Considering the following minimal not working example:

```
import numba as nb
import numpy as np

@nb.jit(nopython=True)
def resize_np_array(np_array, new_size, fill_value):
    if new_size <= np_array.shape[0]:
        return np_array
    else:
        new_shape = np_array.shape
        new_shape[0] = new_size

        new_np_array = fill_value*np.ones(new_shape, dtype=np_array.dtype)

        for i in range(np_array.shape[0]):
            new_np_array[i] = np_array[i]

        return new_np_array

@nb.jit(nopython=True)   
def test_function():
    x = np.zeros(10, dtype=np.int64)
    x = resize_np_array(x, 20, 0)

    return x

x = test_function()
```

The above code will fail with error:

```
  File "A:\anaconda\lib\site-packages\numba\typeinfer.py", line 595, in __call__
    (targetty, self.index, valty), loc=self.loc)

TypingError: Cannot resolve setitem: (int64 x 1)[0] = int64
```

due to the line: `x = resize_np_array(x, 20, 0)` in `test_function`.

How should I go about deleting whatever is stored in `x` so that I can reassign a new array to it?

Comment: Just assign a new array to it.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth That does not work. See the minimal example.

Comment: `new_shape[0] = new_size` would produce an error in regular python.  `new_shape` is a tuple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error is coming from trying to assign a new value to the `shape` attribute of the existing numpy array; that's a fixed thing, you can't just reshape an array by redefining its `shape` attr (in numpy or in numba). (In fact, `shape` is a tuple, which is immutable in any context.) You also don't need to worry about deleting the existing array; python+numpy should handle if all references to the original array go away (after which its memory will be cleaned up). So just create a new array of the desired new shape and assign values to the new array. (Also: use np.full to save a step, or probably faster still, use np.empty and fill only the values you know you need "defaults" in.) The following works (for 1D arrays).

```
import numba as nb

@nb.jit(nopython=True)
def resize_np_array(np_array, new_size, fill_value):
    if new_size <= np_array.shape[0]:
        return np_array
    else:
        new_shape = new_size

        new_np_array = np.empty(shape=new_shape, dtype=np_array.dtype)

        for i in range(np_array.shape[0]):
            new_np_array[i] = np_array[i]

        for i in range(np_array.shape[0], new_shape):
            new_np_array[i] = fill_value

        return new_np_array

@nb.jit(nopython=True)   
def test_function():
    x = np.zeros(10, dtype=np.int64)
    x = resize_np_array(x, 20, 1)

    return x

x = test_function()
```